# Create contour plot + Image without calling figure()

Tags: matlab

Have an existing image in which I am overlaying a contour as per below

```
imshow(I), title(sprintf('contour')), hold on, contour (thresI,'w');
```

Would it be possible to overlay the contour on the image without calling figure? Would like to export the resulting image (into png/jpg) without calling figure()/imshow if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: no. What you probably want though, is to save the figure without plotting. Use the [`'visible'`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) switch:

```
figure;
set(gcf,'visible', 'off');
Imshow(I)
(..) more of your plots
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the figure window so that it's not on the screen:

```
scrsz = get(groot,'ScreenSize');
figure('Position',[-scrsz(4)/2 -scrsz(4)/2 scrsz(3)/2 scrsz(4)/2])
```

so no one will (probably) see it

An other Option is of  course [imwrite](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)

Comment: This works only when you have one screen. And why are you reading `screenSize` when referring to it in figure definition? if you use `figure('units','normalized','positon',[1.1 1.1 w h])` it will be outside the main screen anyway.

Comment: @Crowley, you are correct, and justfor completion: to get all the screensizes `scrsz = get(groot,'MonitorPositions');`, it will return an [Nx4] array where N is the number of monitors

Comment: Is it possible to read the size of the "monitor envelope"? for example we have three very same monitors: left, master, right. The return would be `[-1 0 3 1]` for `units`,`normalized`. In case of monitor layout: top-master-right it would be `[0 0 2 2]`,

Comment: @Crowley as far as i know not directly, but you can always calculate it.

Comment: This does indeed make sure no-one sees the plot, but it will still be generated. It's thus a lot slower than not generating it at all (see my answer)

Comment: @Adriaan The elegance of your answer is when something goes wrong one can easily visualize the figure by setting `visible`,`on`...

Comment: @Adriaam. Since op wants to export the figure i dont think it matters much, it is going  to render the figure at somepoint anyway.

Comment: Rendering and exporting are two different actions. It therefore takes twice as much time to do both actions as opposed to one. I generate surfaces of 200.000 points at least; they take ~5 minutes to load for visualisation and another 3 or so to export them to disk.